# Taking input from user in scheme

Tags: search, random, input, scheme

I want to get input in scheme and after that I want to use these numbers for checking etc How can I do it?
And also I can take random numbers but I can't check them

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) ! Please read  [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) !

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get input in scheme

I think you will probably want to use `read` for that: [https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def.*%28%28quote.*~23~25kernel%29._read%29%29](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reading.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._read%29%29)

> I want to use these numbers for checking etc

What do you mean checking? like comparing? First you will need a variable, let works for most things but perhaps you will want something else in some cases. Let your google-fu help you.

```
(let ((x some-expr))
  ; code block that uses x
```

Then you do whatever "checking" you want like you would with anything else like to see if two strings are the same length and contain the same characters in the same (relative) positions:

```
(string=? "PIE" "PIE")
```

Always with scheme i'd check the (in my opinion) great documentation first: http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/